# How to combine two separate powershell commands

Tags: permissions, powershell, file-permissions

I have several hundred folders that all contain a sub-folder named "Bid Documents".

I need to change the ACL permissions on every instance of those "Bid Documents" folders.

Is there a way to automate this process? I've been told that vbscript is not a good choice for dealing with ACL permissions. I'm imagining a powershell script or something similar that will automatically search the entire folder hierarchy and add the specified ACL permission to every folder named "proposal", but I don't know if this is actually possible, or if there is some other way to accomplish this task.

Thoughts anyone?

Edit:
The comment box keeps messing up my actual powershell command whcih should be as follows:

```
Get-ChildItem "e:\datastore\marcstone bids\*\*\*\Bid Documents" | where {$_.Attributes -eq 'Directory'}
```

The problem is that sometimes the Proposals folder is not always three layers under Marcstone bids, but sometimes only two layers, so when I try the following:

```
Get-ChildItem "e:\datastore\marcstone bids\*\*\Bid Documents" | where {$_.Attributes -eq 'Directory'}
```

Notice how the second version has only two *  This version fails to find any folders though there are many. Why?

Edit again:
This keeps getting more interesting.
Upon examining the results returned by the successful command I discovered it only returns "Bid Documents" folders that are empty. Any "Bid Documents" folders containing any files at all are not returned. Why??

Edit again:
I changed the command to the following and it returned ALL the "bid documents" folders.

```
Get-ChildItem "e:\datastore\marcstone bids\*\*\*\Bid Documents" | where {$_.Attributes -match 'Directory'}
```

Now to learn how to use icacls to change the permissions.

Edit again:
OK, I think I have the correct syntax for icacls with this:

```
icacls *filename* /deny special-restrict1:(f)
```

So, PLEASE someone help me connect these two commands together.

Experimenting with a variable like this:

```
$var = Get-ChildItem "e:\datastore\marcstone bids\1001-3500\1701-1750\1702 Morrow M
emorial Home - Sparta WI\Bid Documents" | where {$_.Attributes -match 'Directory'} | icacls $var /deny special-restrict1
:/F
```

I've selected a specific folder for experimentation purposes. The command returns the following error:

```
First parameter must be a file name pattern or "/?"
```

Thoughts anyone?

Comment: In an effort to prove I am trying hard to work this out. Yes, I'm looking for sympathy :~) I figured out how to search for the folder I want to change, using powershell "Get-ChildItem "e:\datastore\marcstone bids\*\*\*\proposal" | where {$_.Attributes -eq 'Directory'}"  But now how to apply acl permission changes to the results??

Comment: the text box messed up my command which should be  Get-ChildItem "e:\datastore\marcstone bids\*\*\*\Bid Documents" | where {$_.Attributes -eq 'Directory'}

Comment: change  `| icacls $var ..` to `;icacls $var ..` or use pipe object `$_`

Answer (score 0):

icacls is the answer here:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525.aspx

It will allow you to change the acls of a number of folders

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this will help but here goes:

have you tried just storing the Path of the folder you want into a variable
($path E:\datastore\marcstone bids***\Bid Documents )

I don't have the correct environment set up, but just a thought

Comment: I thought that's what I was doing in my example above. With "$var", and then I am trying to use "$var" as the path in the icacls command. But my studying seems to suggest I should be using "out-string -stream" to send one path at a time through the variable to the icacls command. Honestly, this is way over my head and I'm just throwing things at the wall to see if anything sticks.

Comment: if it was me using the path in a variable i would set it like this

$Path = E:\datastore\marcstone bids***\Bid Documents

then implement it into the code with this

Get-ChildItem $Path | where {$_.Attributes -match 'Directory'} | icacls $Path /deny special-restrict1

although Special-restrict 1 isn't a valid parameter thats how i would use the $Path variable

Comment: Why isn't "special-restrict1" a valid parameter? It's the name of a group object... Or do I need the SID? If I need the SID, how many digits of it do I need, because when I looked one up it was like 30-40 digits long.

Comment: /deny Sid:perm explicitly denies the specified user access rights.
    An explicit deny ACE is added for the stated permissions and
    the same permissions in any explicit grant are removed.

That is the extract from the help screen of Powershell for the icacls function. looks like it requires the SiD, id just save it in a variable again 

Hopefully that answers everything

Comment: Hey mate did this solve the issue ?

Comment: Any luck on this? are you able to mark an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try something along these lines:

```
Get-ChildItem "e:\datastore\marcstone bids\*" -include "Bid Documents" -directory -recurse
```

The -recurse parameter should find all the subdirectories no matter how deep they are nested.  The -directory parameter should limit the search to just folders  (directories).  I may have the syntax a little wrong, but it should point you in the right direction.

From there, you should be able to pipe the results to a command that will set the acl for each folder found.

Comment: Not sure any of this works. I have not had time to test any of the ideas put forth here. Sorry... life of a busy IT pro :~)